# How do I append an element with a key using ArrayIterator in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, append, arrayiterator

There is no documentation on the PHP site for the `ArrayIterator` object beyond a basic parameter reference, so I'm not even sure this is possible.

I understand the concept of the `ArrayIterator` in a basic sense like this example:

```
$rows = new ArrayIterator(array('a', 'b', 'c'));
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<p>This is row {$a}.</p>";
}
```

In my case, the rows array is a little more complex (though still simplified for the sake of this example)...

```
$rows = array(
    'a' => NULL,
    'b' => array('d' => NULL, 'e' => NULL, 'f' => NULL),
    'c' => NULL
);
$rows = new ArrayIterator($rows);
```

The idea is that `'b'` in this case, has a number of child elements that should be parsed as if they were parent elements, *at the end* (not necessary to process in order) of the rest of the parent elements (a,b,c).

Normally I would just use...

```
foreach ($child as $c) {
    $rows->append($c);
}
```

But in this case `$child` is an array with a key that I want to maintain...

```
foreach ($child as $key => $c) {
    $rows->append($c);  // but what about $key???
}
```

I don't want to add an array as an element on the end, I want to add the *key* and the *value* to the parent list so we would end up with....

```
$rows = array(
    'a' => ...,
    'b' => ...,
    'c' => ...,
    'd' => ...,
    'e' => ...,
    'f' => ...
);
```

**Question: Is it possible to append an element to the currently iterating array from within a foreach loop *with* a key?**

Comment: `foreach ($child as $c) $rows->append($c);`?

Comment: @u_mulder that would result in the new element being added, but with a numeric key, not the original key 'd' for instance. Sorry there's an error in there, that's a typo, correcting now.

Comment: @u_mulder updated the example to be clearer

Comment: I got it, but I think there's no way to set key for `ArrayIterator`.

Comment: @u_mulder Seems that way, but it also seems like a big shortcoming, was hoping there was yet another undocumented way to do it ;)  After all, they let you read `->key()` but then not write it?

Comment: why? `ArrayIterator` implement `ArrayAccess`. `$rows[$key] = $c;` isn't good for you?

Comment: @Federico will using array method rather than OO work from _inside_ the foreach loop and affect the original array so that they're parsed along with the other parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayIterator` implements `ArrayAccess` interface. That's mean that [`offsetset`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php) is available, and you can assign a value to the specified offset.

As said the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation:

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop
>   precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by
>   reference.

*But in this case isn't needed.*

```
$rows = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => array('d' => 3, 'e' => 4, 'f' => 5),
    'c' => 2
);

$rows = new ArrayIterator($rows);

foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
    if (is_array($row)) { 
        foreach ($row as $key => $c) {
            $rows[$key] = $c;
        }

        // skip this
        continue;
    }

    echo $key, " ", $row, "\n";
}
```

This print:

```
a 1
c 2
d 3
e 4
f 5
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qc6gq).

Comment: Excellent!  Didn't realize I could mix the access methods, learned something new :)  Cheers!

Comment: I just realized that the `&` isn't needed here... just updated my answer